# Tree InOrder Recursion method Explaination

Tags: recursion, data-structures, tree, inorder

Can some one explain me the recursion function flow here in below code how the function is returning when its returning how its printing left right node value.

```
 public void InOrder(Node node) {
        if (node != null) {
          InOrder(node.left);
          System.out.print(" " + node.key);
          InOrder(node.right);
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to imagine what exactly you do not understand here?

- How is the function returning? Like any other function, when it's done. In this case, when the if statement is completed. It is completed, when either the node is null or when it has printed the left subtree, the actual node and the right subtree (in that order).
- How is it printing? By printing the node's key of each node it reaches (after having printed the left subtree).